# MAUI XAML "Window Inspector" no longer visible since updating to 17.3

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui

Sorry for using some made up term but I have no idea what this little menu is called. So I referred to it as "Window Inspector"

[image]

I have 2 systems opening the same project, one is 17.3 preview 6 and the other is 17.3.2.

On the preview version I can see this menu when I debug my MAUI app in Windows.  I cannot see it on the 17.3.2 release, which seems to also be part of a wider debugging issue that I'm experiencing.

Any idea how to fix this?  Maybe I have changed a setting somewhere but am not aware of what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: StackOverflow may not be the best place to get an answer to this question, because MAUI is still relatively new, and VS 2022 is still in preview on some platforms (I'm on Mac M1). MS developers may answer this question faster than SO on their forums. They also know the official name of the widget that you are looking to find :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'm giving that a try too.